# RInside giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, r, rinside

I installed the Rcpp and RInside packages using install.packages.
Then I downloaded the examples and compiled using make. The make failed initially due to some error in sample9.  Once I removed sample9.cpp it all compiled.
Now the issue is that I can't run any of the examples. It seems I get a segmentation fault when I try to instantiate an RInside object.
I downloaded RInside 2.10 from the RInside page and am using R 3.0.2.
Is it a compatibility issue. I am trying to do this on a ubuntu setup.

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff799bbd2 in Rf_isNull () from /usr/lib/libR.so
#1  0x00007ffff768a103 in Rcpp_ReplaceObject (y=0x0, x=0x0) at /usr/local/lib/R/site-   library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:107
#2  set__ (x=0x0, this=0x7fffffffe4f8) at /usr/local/lib/R/site-   library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/storage/PreserveStorage.h:18
#3  Environment_Impl (this=0x7fffffffe4f8) at /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Environment.h:46
#4  RInside::RInside (this=0x7fffffffe4f0, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe638, loadRcpp=false, verbose=false, interactive=false) at RInside.cpp:91
#5  0x0000000000402adf in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ffff6dc676d in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000402d55 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fffffffe628 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffffffe848 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

This is the gdb trace. I wasn't able to make much sense of it but hope may be others can.

Came across this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rcpp/6740 in my further research. Looked similar to what I am facing. Is this a known issue which is being fixed?

Comment: i removed the package installed using install.package and reinstalled using install_github and it works.

Comment: Yes, I'll get a fixed version to CRAN "shortly". In the meantime, installation from GitHub it is. This was caused by the recent Rcpp upgrade, and we failed to catch it in time.

Comment: Would you advise to wait till the fixed version is ported to CRAN or can i go ahead and start using the github version?

Comment: Your call. RInside 0.2.11 is now on CRAN :)

Comment: I had the same problem just an hour ago. This is caused by the non instantaneous propagation of packages to mirrors. This issue will surely disappear with time but until then choose mirror wisely and keep eye on the version. `75: USA (CA 1)` mirror has the proper version at the time of writing.

Comment: Also partly my fault. I tested package prior to releasing Rcpp 0.11.0.  RInside still compiled, but I overlooked the segfault. We try not to break on updates, but Rcpp 0.11.0 is a big one.